# Why does my function return undefined, especially the .split()parts?

Tags: javascript, html

So in essence I get the value of input, then try to divide into into different tags via the comma with this

```
     var noteTags = document.getElementsByClassName("noteTag").value;
          Tag = noteTags.split(",");
```

But in console, the `split(",")` is `undefined`
Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention that the noteTag element is input, does this change how the code works in any way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getElementsByClassName doesn't work, but getElementById does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178138/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-but-getelementbyid-does)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: "But in console, the split(",") is 'undefined'" - no it's not, please read the message again more thoroughly. It says probably "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')". So it says, the property "split" of an undefined value cannot be read. So, that means, **`noteTags` must have been `undefined`** (not the result of `split`) so that it tried to do `undefined.split(",")`! And why is that? Because you accessed the `value` property of whatever `getElementsByClassName` returned and it was `undefined`, so you did something wrong there. (As noted, a `NodeList` doesn't have a `value`.)

Comment: Wow I never considered that the value .split(",") was used with was undefined, that would have been a lot easier to resolve, thanks

Comment: Wat exactly does getElementById('').value actually return, a string or some other data type?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues,

1. [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like collection of elements (a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)).
2. And instead of `value` it should be `innerText`.

Try like below

```
 var noteTags = document.getElementsByClassName("noteTag")[0].innerText;
      Tag = noteTags.split(",");
```

Comment: It is an array-like collection. Subtle differences from an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **split()** method on an array. You are also trying to access the **value** property, whereby you should probably use **innerText**.

Comment: Thanks,I thought .split could be also be used for non Array objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` then you dont need using a key[0] to select the element.

```js
const noteTags = document.querySelector("#noteTag");
console.log(noteTags)
Tag = noteTags.innerHTML.split(",");
console.log(Tag)
```

```html
<div id="noteTag">en,jp,fr</div>
```

Comment: I tried this in the program but it didn't work.It should have tho since when I ran the code snippet(on stackoverflow) it did.Any advice?

Comment: @LiamOsvaldo it should be work. output if i will run over SO: `[
  "en",
  "jp",
  "fr"
]`